# Dynamically convert rows to columns in MariaDB 10.3

Tags: mariadb, pivot-table, mariadb-10.3

I have the following table data:

| teams | tournament | assoc | player_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MT | 101 | EGY | 100696 |
| MT | 101 | EGY | 100439 |
| MT | 101 | EGY | 102486 |
| MT | 101 | EGY | 111887 |
| MT | 101 | NGR | 113563 |
| MT | 101 | NGR | 111959 |
| MT | 101 | NGR | 145024 |
| MT | 101 | NGR | 104514 |
| MT | 101 | NGR | 112092 |
| WT | 101 | EGY | 202375 |
| WT | 101 | EGY | 116724 |
| WT | 101 | EGY | 134971 |
| WT | 101 | EGY | 200157 |
| WT | 101 | NGR | 102441 |
| WT | 101 | NGR | 146169 |
| WT | 101 | NGR | 134970 |
| WT | 101 | NGR | 133736 |
| WT | 101 | NGR | 101247 |

I would like to transpose rows to columns and get the following:

| teams | tournament | assoc | player_id1 | player_id2 | player_id3 | player_id4 | player_id5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MT | 101 | EGY | 100696 | 100439 | 102486 | 111887 |  |
| MT | 101 | NGR | 113563 | 111959 | 145024 | 104514 | 112092 |
| WT | 101 | EGY | 202375 | 116724 | 134971 | 200157 |  |
| WT | 101 | NGR | 102441 | 146169 | 134970 | 133736 | 101247 |

Needs to group by assoc, tournament and teams and max columns of player_idx can be 5.
Tried solutions for Pivot tables with no success.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? I.e. what does `SELECT VERSION();` report?

Comment: In a given tournament, how do you determine which player is player1, player2, etc.?

Comment: @BillKarwin 10.3.35-MariaDB-cll-lve

Comment: @BillKarwin it doesn't matter who is player1, player2.

Comment: I edited your title and tags, because you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. Although MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, and they still have a lot of code in common, you should not think of MariaDB as the same as MySQL, or even guaranteed to be compatible anymore. Both products have advanced since the fork.

Comment: @BillKarwin You are right. I should have mentioned MariaDB and not MySQL. Thanks for your help. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (select teams, tournament, assoc, player_id, row_number() over (partition by teams, tournament, assoc) as rownum from mytable)
select teams, tournament, assoc,
  max(case rownum when 1 then player_id end) as player_id1,
  max(case rownum when 2 then player_id end) as player_id2,
  max(case rownum when 3 then player_id end) as player_id3,
  max(case rownum when 4 then player_id end) as player_id4,
  max(case rownum when 5 then player_id end) as player_id5
from cte
group by teams, tournament, assoc;

+-------+------------+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| teams | tournament | assoc | player_id1 | player_id2 | player_id3 | player_id4 | player_id5 |
+-------+------------+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| MT    |        101 | EGY   |     100439 |     100696 |     102486 |     111887 |       NULL |
| MT    |        101 | NGR   |     104514 |     111959 |     112092 |     113563 |     145024 |
| WT    |        101 | EGY   |     116724 |     134971 |     200157 |     202375 |       NULL |
| WT    |        101 | NGR   |     101247 |     102441 |     133736 |     134970 |     146169 |
+-------+------------+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Tested on MySQL 8.0, and on this dbfiddle on MariaDB 10.3:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ec2fc62b17fdc5eac9198f9298f229cc